# What is the general word that describes following relationsip

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-request

I have a problem finding correct English word that describes following situation:

"Opel, car brand in Germany sell identical cars in UK under brand Vauxhall."

I'm interesting in English word that describes this relationship in any context, best I could think of was joint venture needless to say way I ask you for better term.

Comment: The situation you described is *obscure*, I'm afraid. Could you please explain it further?

Comment: I don't know about any joint venture: both companies were owned by General Motors until 2017 when they were bought by Groupe PSA. Some Vauxhall cars are manufactured in Germany, some in UK. Vauxhall is the UK brand. I would not call the cars *identical*: left or right hand drive, and probably some differences relating to each country's construction & use regulations. So they share the same design.

Comment: @WeatherVane while I agree both cars are not identical I think they are in terms of some generalized standard. Wikipedia is pretty clear, see 2nd paragraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vauxhall_Motors

Comment: Both comments set the right direction, if both cars are identical only difference lies in companies which make Vauxhall a subsidiary of Opel. Brain fuck sorry how do I add point to both of you

Comment: You need some determiners in that sentence. [interested **in** English] and verbs should probably be in the past tense. Opel-branded cars.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to start your sentence with the subject, which is the company called Groupe PSA.  This company is selling cars in two different markets, Germany and the UK'

Groupe PSA sells cars in Germany under the Opel name and a similar line in the Uk under the  brand name Vauxhall.

It was hard to tell if you were talking about a single model of car or a line of cars. If one company owns both brands, it is not a joint venture.  A joint venture is a commercial enterprise undertaken jointly by two or more parties which otherwise retain their distinct identities. (def. from a Bing search).

Answer (score 2):

The process of deciding what name to use, or using that name, is called **(re)branding**.

For instance, automakers are notorious for selling models under different brands in different places. This is often to take advantage of better “name recognition” in each market. For instance, Grope PSA might brand all their cars as Vauxhall in the UK and as Opel in Germany, regardless of which company’s factory made them.

They even sometimes use multiple brands in the same market for the same car. For instance, Ford may sell the basic (and less expensive) variant branded as a Ford but rebrand higher end (and more expensive) variants as Mercury, even though they come out of the same factory and are sold at the same dealerships.

You can also rebrand an entire company. For instance, after a crash, budget airline ValuJet rebranded themselves as Air Tran to get some distance from all the bad publicity.